# NP Reduction from 3Color to QuadProg

Tags: np-complete, quadratic-programming

i just signed up here because im struggling very hard with a problem i gotta solve. What I wanna do is reducing an Instance of 3color to an instance of Quadprog to prove that quadprog is np-hard, and i have no idea how to do that. My first idea was to match every node to a varaible of quadprog, but i have no clue how to continue. Maybe anyone here knows how to help me?

Comment: How do you know it's even possible?

Comment: Well, its a task I got to do for my studys, and they wont give us tasks that have no solution. And furthermore, every NP-complete problem can be reduces to every other np-complete problem, as far as i know

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean by *Quadprog*.